# Can SysInternals' Process Monitor log when a thread blocks awaiting for an event?

Tags: windows, windbg, procmon

I need to diagnose a server that is unable to reach peak performance.  CPU usage drops to zero for around 500ms and then spikes to 100% while trying to process the queued requests, this pattern repeats during a number of hours after which the operation becomes smooth again (Operation had been smooth for years)

This suggests to me that the worker threads are idling while awaiting for an external event to occur.  The application is complex and we haven't been able to pinpoint the culprit.

**Can Process Monitor be configured to log every time a thread sleeps awaiting for some event?**
If possible, can the event be related to a particular stack trace?

If the above is possible, perhaps I could correlate the CPU drops with wait events and pinpoint the culprit.

I have successfully used Windbg before to diagnose these kinds of problems, however in this case, the wait is very brief and I'm not confident that I can make the debugger break exactly while the processor is idling.

Comment: use ETW to diag this: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis

Comment: Wow, this is EXACTLY the right tool for the job. Would love to vote your answer if you post it as such.  Cheers!

Comment: ok, in this case I've posted an answer so that [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windbg and ProcMon are not the right tools for this job. Install the **Windows Performance Toolkit** which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) on your Developer device.

[image]

Now xcopy the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit` to the server, open `cmd.exe` as admin and run `wpr.exe -start CPU && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\Hang.etl`, now minimize the cmd.

After you got the hang, switch back to cmd and press a key to stop logging.

Move the Hang.etl + NGENPDB folder to the dev PC, open the `Hang.etl` with **Windows Performance Analyzer** (`WPA.exe`), load [debug symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/load-symbols-or-configure-symbol-paths) and start [finding the hang](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis#time=05m15s) by adding the CPU (Precise) to analysis pane

[image]

and make sour you see the columns NewProcess, NewThreadId, NewStack, ReadyingProcess, ReadyingThreadId, ReadyingStack, Waits(us). Click on `Waits(us)` to see most long on top. Now look for long times, with a small Count (so small operations that take long time, not many operations) and inspect the callstack to have any clues what happens.